Distribution of a stochastic integral $\int_0^t W_1(s) dW_2(s)$ with independent $W_1$ and $W_2$.
Consider two independent 1-d Wiener processes $W_1(t)$ and $W_2(t)$ with $W_1(0) = W_2(0) = 0$.
I would like to know the distribution of the process
$$Y(t) = \int_0^t W_1(s)dW_2(s). \tag{1}$$
I reason that since $W_1(t)$ and $W_2(t)$ are independent, we can treat (1) using the usual calculus. For example, we can use the integration by parts to rewrite (1) as:
$$\int_0^t \underbrace{W_1(s)}_{u}\underbrace{dW_2(s)}_{dv} = W_1(t)W_2(t) - \int_0^t W_2(s)dW_1(s).$$
Now, we can clearly see that we have a product $W_1(t) W_2(t)$ of two normally distributed variables. Therefore, (1) can't be normal.
Also, using a partition $P_N = \{t_0, \ldots, t_N\}$ of the interval $[0,t]$, we can show:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t W_1(s)dW_2(s) \right] = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j=0}^{N} \mathbb{E}[W_1(t_j)]\mathbb{E}[W_2(t_{j+1})-W_2(t_j)] = 0,$$
and
$$\mathbb{E}\left [ \left( \int_0^t W_1(s)dW_2(s) \right)^2 \right] = \int_0^t \mathbb{E}[W_1(s)^2]ds = \int_0^t s \ ds = \frac{t^2}{2}.$$
So, the mean and variance are zero and $t^2/2$, respectively, but I have no idea what the distribution is and if it has a closed form at all.
If it is tough to get an analytical description of the density function of $Y(t)$, would it be reasonable to approximate the distribution with $N(0, t^2/2)$?

have you seen this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298661/integral-of-brownian-motion-with-respect-to-an-independent-brownian-motion

I believe, this paper answers precisely your question https://samos.univ-paris1.fr/archives/ftp/preprints/samos239.pdf the result itself apparently is given in [6] and [17], but I'm not sure how's your French

@SBF, thank you very much! The first paper is almost exactly what I need; unfortunately, the integral has fixed bounds, and the reference paper is in French.  I'll try to read it anyway.

@SBF, the paper trail brought me to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_stochastic_area

I think you should be able to rescale your original integral to the unit interval. Will that fully answer your question?

@SBF, how rescale and why it should work?

Regarding scaling, you know that if you scale the time of Brownian motion this is the same as scaling its value?

For your approximation, the first problem that you have to solve is the following: let $X_i,Y_j $ independent $N(0,1)$, what is the distribution of $$A_N=\sum_{j=1}^N(\sum_{i=1}^j X_i)Y_j$$? Clearly $$E(e^{it A_N})=E(E(e^{itA_N}|X))=E(e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}\sum_{j=1}^N(\sum_{i=1}^j X_i)^2})=E(e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}X^T\Sigma X})$$$$=\frac{1}{(\det (I_N+t^2\Sigma))^{1/2}}=\prod_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2\lambda_i}}$$ where $\Sigma$ is the matrix of the quadratic form $X\mapsto \sum_{j=1}^N(\sum_{i=1}^j X_i)^2$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i.$ I think that $\Sigma$ have its eigenvalues quite explicit, but it takes a bit of time to remember. Anyway since $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=E(e^{it{\sqrt{2V}Z}})$$ where $V\sim \Gamma(1/2)$ is independent of $Z\sim N(0,1)$ we get that $$ A_N=\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i\sqrt{2V_i}Z_i$$ is a sum of iid rv.
The quick calculation above is probably full of little coefficient mistakes and missing square roots. I will compute the eigenvalues but I am sure that you or somebody of the site will do it before.
